# libc++.so.6 out of date on beaglebone black

Tags: arm, embedded, cross-compiling, beagleboneblack

I'm having an interesting issue when I'm trying to run a cross compiled image on my beaglebone black.  Currently I'm building my executable on my linux machine then sftping it over to my beaglebone black.  I have a simple Hello World program working just fine, but when I attempt to run a slightly more complicated program I get an error running the executable on the beaglebone black.  The beagle bone says "libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' wrong version" (paraphrasing the last bit).
I've tried updating my tools on the beaglebone but nothing has helped.  I read somewhere that I might need to add -static to the build flags but that has helped.

Here a link to my github project with my makefile: https://github.com/Cwillforeal/RoboProject.  I know sometime the ordering can be an issue with flags but it seems fine.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Found answer, I'm dumb, need to put -static in the linker flags not the g++ flags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put -static in the LINKER build command, I feel dumb.